# How to use webdirverio in typescript project, or please provide high level overview of how to refer to types defined in imported packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, webdriver-io

**This is the specific case I've been working on**, below it, further down, is the original more general question.

- I'm trying to create a private npm package for e2e testing of a website.
- I need to use the `webdriverio` package.
- I want the user to be able to start my executable with a provided configuration, one part of this configuration must be a `webdriverio` config (actually a subset of it, since I'd like to restrict some options). The other part of the configuration is related to my package: user login name etc.

To achieve this, I've declared my own type and expect the user's argument to conform to it.

But the problem is that when I try to compile the code, which declares that type, I get errors like:

`Argument of type '{ … } is not assignable to parameter of type 'RemoteOptions'`

`Types of property 'logLevel' are incompatible`

`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'WebDriverLogTypes | undefined'.`

The code, which declares that type is (I left the comments just to demonstrate attempts I'd tried to fix this):

```
//import { WebdriverIO } from '@wdio/types';

type TestUserConfig = {
  //wdioConfig: WebdriverIO,
  wdioConfig: {
    path: '/wd/hub',
    automationProtocol: 'webdriver',
    //logLevel: 'trace' | 'debug' | 'info' | 'warn' | 'error' | 'silent',
    logLevel: string,
    waitforTimeout: number,
    capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome',
    },
  },
  domain: string,
  userLogin: string,
  userPassword: string,
  googleAuthSecret: string,
  expectedRole: string,
}

export type {
  TestUserConfig,
}
```

The problem is that if I try to refer to those webdriverio types directly, like:

```
logLevel: WebDriverLogTypes,
```

I get errors like `Cannot find name 'WebDriverLogTypes'`

If I try to import that type like:

```
import {WebDriverLogTypes} from '@wdio/types';
```

I ger errors like: `Module '"@wdio/types"' has no exported member 'WebDriverLogTypes'`

---

**The original question:**

Suppose there is a nodejs package (I won't call it module, since I mean a module, but not a module of mine, which is under my control, but a module installed via `npm`). That package exports a function, which expects certain type as its argument:

```
type Foo = 'foo';
export default function otherModule(arg: Foo) {}
```

Now, when I use this module, I want typescript to correctly catch type errors, so that an attempt to compile this TypeScript code throws an error:

```
import otherModule from 'other-module';
otherModule('bar');
```

What would be the commonly accepted (probably the best) approach to achieve this?

---

I've seen some packages have '@types/*' packages too, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

**A general approach to use types for other imported libraries/packages etc.:**

If the imported library has been developed in JavaScript it, most likely, doesn't have any type definitions out of the box, so in this case there are only these solutions:

- check if there is a type definition for this library (usually it may be the '@types/{libraryName}' package or something else, if it's provided in the library docs.
- create a type declaration yourself for this library: see the [Ambient declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries) in the TypeScript docs.

Then import that declaration and use it to refer to types from that library.

---

**For my specific case with webdriverio, I've ended up with the next solution.**

Since webdriverio is apparently developed with TypeScript it already has its own type declarations.

So I just looked into the @wdio/types package to see where is that WebDriverLogTypes type had been declared and used that namespace to reference that type:

```
import type { Options } from '@wdio/types';

type TestUserConfig = {
  wdioConfig: {
    path: '/wd/hub',
    automationProtocol: 'webdriver',
    logLevel: Options.WebDriverLogTypes,
    waitforTimeout: number,
    capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome',
    },
  },
  domain: string,
  userLogin: string,
  userPassword: string,
  googleAuthSecret: string,
  expectedRole: string,
}

export type {
  TestUserConfig,
}
```